# Add specific object into collection with in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular, in-memory-database

I am developing my project and for testing phase I am using in-memory-web-api of angular npm package.

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from "angular-in-memory-web-api";

  export class FakeBackendService implements InMemoryDbService{
  createDb(){
        let users = [
        {
            id: 1, 
            username: 'maulik',  
            city: 'ABC', 
            state: 'xyz', 
            role: 'admin',
            courses: []
        },
        {
            id: 2, 
            username: 'donald', 
            city: 'poi', 
            state: 'bnv', 
            role: 'Student',
            courses: [
                {
                    courseId: 23,
                    course_name: 'Data visualisation',
                    preRequistics: 'NA',
                    instructor_name: 'maulik',
                    duration: 23,
                    status: 'In-progress',
                }
            ]
        }

    ];
  }
```

Now, I want to add one object inside course array of id:2 like below:

```
 courses: [
                {
                    courseId: 23,
                    course_name: 'Data visualisation',
                    preRequistics: 'NA',
                    instructor_name: 'maulik',
                    duration: 23,
                    status: 'In-progress',
                },
                {
                    courseId: 28,
                    course_name: 'Django',
                    preRequistics: '',
                    instructor_name: 'maulik',
                    duration: 80,
                    status: 'In-progress',
                }
            ]
```

So, I want to add new object (update) inside course array. So using PUT or POST method how can I write API for that ? I tried below code using PUT but no success. Can anyone help me with that?

> const url = '${this.url}/?courses=${data.object}'

Answer (score 0):

To add / insert a new record to your data set use HTTP POST.

The Angular in-memory provider will intercept any HTTP request to your in-memory data service. You can try something like this:

```
addCourse(course: Course): Observable<Course> {
    return this.http.post<Course>(this.Url, course, this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
            tap((newCourse: Course) => 
                this.log(`added course with id=${newCourse.id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<Course>('addCourse'))
        );
}
```

Using the HTTP PUT requires you to use an existing record id, which is only useful for updating an existing record. So in this case use the HTTP POST.

Comment: Thanks but I want to update (add object inside) course: [] Array for existing object id : 2. Above method creates a new record.

Comment: You can try : users.courses.push(object) in your data service, however just adding courses into the users object isn't a good idea as you would not be able to maintain changes to course records that are copies of objects within a users object. Are you planning to use a SQL database to persist the objects in production?

Answer (score 0):

I just made several trial and error and found solution using PUT method.

```
updateCourse(courseObj){
   return this.http.put(this.base_url, courseObj)
          .pipe(map(res => res));
}
```

It updates existing record as follows:

```
courses: [
                {
                    courseId: 3,
                    course_name: 'Angular',
                    preRequistics: 'typescript',
                    instructor_name: 'donald',
                    duration: 5,
                    status: 'In-progress',
                    noOfEnrolledStudents: 18
                },
                {
                    courseId: 4,
                    course_name: 'new course added',
                    preRequistics: 'NA',
                    instructor_name: 'George',
                    duration: 8,
                    status: 'In-progress',
                    noOfEnrolledStudents: 0
                }
            ]
```